# Train-Validation-Test Split for Pneumonia Xray Classification

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, image-classification

I recently came across a dataset named Pneumonia X-Ray Images (https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/pcbreviglieri/pneumonia-xray-images) prepared by Paulo Breviglieri on Kaggle, and I noticed the split of the dataset into training, validation, and testing sets. I found the distribution of observations to be as follows:

- Training observations: 4,192 (1,082 normal cases, 3,110 lung opacity
  cases)
- Validation observations: 1,040 (267 normal cases, 773 lung    opacity
  cases)
- Testing observations: 624 (234 normal cases, 390 lung    opacity
  cases)

I have a question regarding the choice of this particular split. Typically, the validation set is smaller than the testing set, as it is commonly used for fine-tuning and hyperparameter tuning during the model development process. However, in this dataset, the validation set consists of approximately 17.76% of the total observations, while the testing set comprises around 10.65% of the total observations.

I'm interested to learn more about the reasoning behind this split. Could anyone kindly explain why he chose to allocate a larger percentage to the validation set and a smaller percentage to the testing set? Were there specific considerations or goals while determining this distribution?

TIA.